# Apache HTTP client org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException even after lower validateAfterInactivity

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have HTTP client and it receiving following error occasionally. At the time of this exception receive the actual request is not hit the target server.

`org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: xxxx:yy failed to respond; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: xxxx:yy failed to respond`

Apache http client version : 4.5.13

I have reduced the validateAfterInactivity to 100ms but no luck. Still I am receiving the errors in same rate.

My HttpClient pool configuration is in below.

```
    public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager result = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        result.setMaxTotal(500);
        result.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(75);
        result.setValidateAfterInactivity(100);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was able to sort out by adding both HttpRequestRetryHandler and setValidateAfterInactivity.

```
httpClientBuilder.setRetryHandler(new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {
               @Override
               public boolean retryRequest(java.io.IOException exception, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {
                   if (executionCount > 2) {
                       log.warn("Skipped retry");
                       return false;
                   }
                   if (exception instanceof org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) {
                       log.warn("Executed retry " + exception.getMessage());
                       return true;
                   }
                   return false;
               }
           });
```